# Next.js 13 next intl redirect localhost3000

Tags: next.js, localization, internationalization, i18next, next-intl

the problem is this, I have 2 locales uk and en , the default is ua , the site is already uploaded to the hosting , test.com/ua redirects to localhost3000 and if test.com/en it opens without problems, it’s irreversible if the default is changed. Maybe you can tell what is the problem ? tried on a clean build and the same result

I have already done it several times according to the documentation and videos, but it still redirects to localhost3000

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions from my understanding,

1. @Olexiy Zhevakin, Please check your middleware file. Did you written any rewrite function in that ?
2. Remove all the files from your publish folder and do deploy again when your local development server is running correct.

Comment: Good afternoon
I have attached a photo and comment below.